# When adding ListView builder , the entire screen is goes blank

Tags: flutter, dart

when I try to add a list view builder, my entire screen goes black
here is the list view builder code

```
ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap = true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final data = courseCardList[index];
                  return Row(
                    children: [
                      CourseList(
                        color: data.color,
                        icon: data.icon,
                        caption: data.caption,
                        head: data.head,
                        timePeriod: data.timePeriod,
                        rating: data.rating,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
```

when I build the UI, that shows a blank screen, what mistake am I making here?

Comment: Can you share your full code snippet to understand better way, BTW I think here is something missing that "courseCardList[index] change to courseCardList[index].length"

Comment: Add `itemCount: courseCardList.length`

Comment: its not working

Comment: @SaifulIslam added the code , please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Horizontal Listview.builder needs a fixed height.** Horizontal list item shouldn't have a endless height. so solution came to my mind just wrap Listview.builder with a conatiner and set height of that container like below.

The Flutter framework can only know the height of a widget once it's been built.

If you're building ListView children dynamically, it can't calculate the required height of the ListView until all it's children have been built, which might never happen (infinite ListView).

You can either give the ListView a fixed height and build its children dynamically or have the ListView's height depend on it's children.

```
Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap = true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final data = courseCardList[index];
                      return Row(
                        children: [
                          CourseList(
                            color: data.color,
                            icon: data.icon,
                            caption: data.caption,
                            head: data.head,
                            timePeriod: data.timePeriod,
                            rating: data.rating,
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

Under `ListView Widget`

1. use `shrinkWrap: true`
2. add itemCount, `itemCount: courseCardList.length`

If it still doesn't solve the issue,

Remove the `Row()` widget as I can see you are only returning a single widget under it, so directly return that widget `CourseList()`

The code should look something like this.

```
ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap : true,
            itemCount: courseCardList.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final data = courseCardList[index];
              return CourseList(
                      color: data.color,
                      icon: data.icon,
                      caption: data.caption,
                      head: data.head,
                      timePeriod: data.timePeriod,
                      rating: data.rating,
                  );
            },
          ),
```

Comment: its not working when ```scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,``` changes to vertical its working fine but vertically scroll, i need that as in horizontal

Comment: what's not working, can you share the issue?

Comment: its done bro, all i need to do was give a fixed height and width, now its done

Comment: fixed height and width is not a dynamic or good solution, as problems will occur to various devices with different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `itemCount`

```
Expanded(
     child:ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap = true,
            itemCount = 5,// add this line or put courseCardList.length
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final data = courseCardList[index];
              return Row(
                children: [
                  CourseList(
                    color: data.color,
                    icon: data.icon,
                    caption: data.caption,
                    head: data.head,
                    timePeriod: data.timePeriod,
                    rating: data.rating,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
      ),
```

Refer [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) and [`Long List`](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

Answer (score -1):

provide itemCount to your ListviewBuilder and also wrap it with Expanded or some fixed size widget like container like:

```js
Expanded(
child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: your counts(int)
    .....
    .....
  )
)
```

Comment: no i added the item count now, but i can only scroll down, when i set axis to horizontal its just blank only the part again